# Silverlight Handle App MouseLeftButtonDown?

Tags: silverlight, mouseleftbuttondown

In my silverlight project I have a Menu, that I want to **close it** if I click **anywhere outside it**. I add handler to the click event on App:

```
AddHandler App.Current.RootVisual.MouseLeftButtonDown, AddressOf HideMenu
```

But the **problem** that: **it does not enter the Handler when I click on any other command**, or click on the same control that have the context menu, it is enter only when I click on an empty area outside the menu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't aware that was a signature of `AddHandler` that only takes 2 parameters, perhaps its a VB thing that you are getting away with it and its defaulting the third parameter to `False`.  This parameter is the *handledEventsToo* parameter which indicates you want your handler to execute even when some other control has handled the event.

I guess the VB would look like this:-

```
AddHandler App.Current.RootVisual.MouseLeftButtonDown, AddressOf HideMenu, True
```

**Edit**

Lets ditch this VB code which is wrong anyway.  Here is what the code should look like in C# (you must be fairly familar with translating since the vast majority of code examples on the Web for silverlight will be in C#).

```
 this.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, HideMenu, true);
```

Where this code is in the code behind of the containing UserControl and `HideMenu` has this signature:-

```
 void HideMenu(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
 }
```